# How to create a horizontal and vertical line on winning pattern in a tic-tac-toe game (in android studio)

Tags: android-layout

I am a beginner to Android and I am building a **Tic-Tac-Toe** game and I am having a 3 by 3  **GridLayout** with images of Circles and Crosses.

But I don't know how the create the horizontal/vertical/diagonal lines on the winning pattern.(If it's animated I will be obliged)

Please help me guys by suggesting the correct syntax

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="395dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:rowCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="1"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="2"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="3"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="4"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="5"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="6"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="7"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="8"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_row="0" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Are you talking about how to edit your xml file to have lines in it?

Comment: Yes, but in a grid layout. But if you want, I can post code also

Answer (score 0):

Use this to draw a vertical line (top - down):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

and this for a horizontal line (left- right):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```